# Python winreg module access denied

Tags: python, registry, winreg

Here is my code:

```
import winreg as wreg
key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters',wreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
wreg.SetValueEx(key,"IPEnableRouter", 0, wreg.REG_DWORD, 1)
```

When i run this script, it says

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is Denied
```

How to change the value as 0 to 1 or 1 to 0?

Comment: try in an elevated shell. But not guaranteed it will work.

Comment: I tried to run cmd as administrator and run the script. But still the same error. UAC etc. is already lowest level i don't know if it is important

Comment: Are you attempting to access the 32 bit registry? or the 64 bit one? Maybe try using (KEY_WOW64_64KEY + KEY_QUERY_VALUE) or (KEY_WOW64_32KEY + KEY_QUERY_VALUE) for your search flag

Comment: Well, i tried this "wreg.SetValueEx(key,"IPEnableRouter",  wreg.REG_DWORD, 1,wreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)" and "key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters',wreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS,wreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)" Both gives the same error.

Comment: any more idea? please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three things to try:

1. Add an extra `0` to your parameters for the `res`. Currently you not setting the `sam`.
2. Use the Registry Editor to change the permissions on the key to allow you as a user to have access.

[image: Regedit screenshot]

3. It is better to always request the minimum required access, so I would recommend you use `wreg.KEY_SET_VALUE` instead of `wreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS`.

So the script would be as follows:

```
import _winreg as wreg

key = wreg.OpenKey(wreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters', 0, wreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
wreg.SetValueEx(key, "IPEnableRouter", 1, wreg.REG_DWORD, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, i mean, there is no error. But i couldn't understand which integer sets the value. I changed to 0 all of them but regedit still says "0x000001(1)"

Comment: It is actually the last parameter that sets the value, see [`SetValueEx`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html?highlight=winreg#_winreg.SetValueEx). If you are looking in regedit, don't forget to refresh the display with F5 after you run the script.

Comment: Ah.. my bad. Yes i forgot "f5", even i saw the correct value when i click. So thanks for your effoor and time